# Getting 404 - Not Found when trying to access Stack Overflow from chrome

Tags: bug, google-chrome

So when I try to access Stack Overflow from chrome I get

> 404 - Not Found

But when I try from Microsoft Edge it works. I have no idea why, any help would be appreciated thanks.

I'm on Windows 10.

Chrome Version : Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: What URL, exactly?

Comment: All of them haha, even my own profile : http://stackoverflow.com/users/7503064/cnuts

Comment: ya im getting something different now im getting : Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from stackoverflow.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: Does [https://stackoverflow.com/users/7503064/cnuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7503064/cnuts) work? (https that is)

Comment: (Sorry anybody reading this, I screwed up the comment flow, imagine my last comment before CNuts last comment).

Comment: Ya still getting the privacy thing

Comment: Do the URLs work in an incognito tab in chrome?

Comment: No i get the same thing.

Comment: @CNuts What version of Chrome are you using? Make sure it is the latest.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS My version is Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit), I downloaded it probably like 2 days ago.

Comment: @CNuts Can you post a screenshot of the 404 page you are getting? Curious if it's the one generated by SO or if it's one generated by something else along the way.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried restarting Chrome?

Comment: I've added the picture @JasonC

Comment: @enderland If by restart you mean close chrome and reopen it ya i tried.

Comment: @JasonC Should i try the Proceed to stackoverflow.com (unsafe)?

Comment: @CNuts Me being paranoid (and also not having a good understanding of web security in general), would do that in an incognito tab and not log in. There have been a lot of changes to the sites recently involving a switchover to HTTPS, and this may or may not be related, but no sense not being cautious until you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @JasonC Okay so i did it in the incognito tab and got the same 404 - Not Found.

Comment: Btw, that doesn't look like a default Chrome 404 page or an SE-generated one. Are you at an office or university, behind some firewall?

Comment: @JasonC No im at my house it was working like 5min before i posted this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qi5rx7PgK34&t=70

Comment: @CNuts Did you install any antivirus software recently? Like Kaspersky?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS I had to to reinstall windows completly because of the last update. My pc froze during the update and then kept rebooting. Dont know if its related.

Comment: @CNuts This would be easier if you [came to chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

Comment: So restarting my pc ended up fixing this problem.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Got a new problem today i added the picture to the question. Havn't tried restarting my pc yet but maybe this will help you guys figure why it happens.

Comment: @CNuts That's a different problem. You ought to ask it as a different question. I suppose it could be *related*, so you might want to link back to this question in your new one. But this post is pretty much case-closed, so, time for a new post.

Comment: @JasonC Im pretty sure if i restart my pc it should fix it but like it looks like these thing are happening often so should i still post it as a question?

Comment: You have two choices: Post it as a new question, or you *could* leave your edit here but now you have to wait for this post to get reopened. It's up to you, whatever you think will get you an answer more effectively.

Comment: @JasonC Okay there it is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292575/this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-style-information-associated-with-it