# "Access Denied" when accessing Stack Overflow from Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome

I get this error when I want to access anything on Stack Overflow using Chrome:

[image]

Additionally, in the Chrome developer console, I am seeing (for example):

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/users/7503064/cnuts 403 (Forbidden)
```

I had a kind of related error, which I posted as a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292548/getting-404-not-found-when-trying-to-access-stack-overflow-from-chrome?noredirect=1#comment950470_292548). Restarting my PC seems to fix those problems, but they're happening really often and are really weird. How could I make this stop?

Some other information:

- I am at home, not behind a corporate or university firewall.
- The issue started suddenly yesterday and has continued.
- I am using Chrome version 57, it was just installed a few days ago.
- I do not have any antivirus software installed. The Windows install is fresh. The only extension I have installed is AdBlock.
- Disabling extensions does not fix the issue.
- Clearing the cache does not fix the issue.
- The domain seems to be resolving to the correct IP address. The output of `nslookup stackoverflow.com` is:

  ```
  Server: UnKnown
  Address: 192.168.1.1

  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name: stackoverflow.com
  Address: 151.101.129.69
  ```
- The problem does not occur with Microsoft Edge.
- It seems the problem occasionally happens from another machine in my house as well.

Comment: It works in Edge, though, right? And what about in an incognito tab (which does not load extensions)?

Comment: @JasonC It works in edge and  for the incognito it does that your connection is not private thing.

Comment: So, I don't have any ideas here (somebody else might) but what I can say for certain is this *definitely* seems to be an issue with something on your machine, and not an SE issue. So it's tricky. Does anything interesting show up in the chrome developer console (Ctrl+Shift+I)? If you go to the Network tab in that console then reload the page do you see anything funny? What about messages in the Console tab?

Comment: @JasonC In the console im getting `GET http://stackoverflow.com/users/7503064/cnuts 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: As with your other issue, does this one persist when you disable extensions?

Comment: Ya its the same with or without them. @JasonC

Comment: If you clear your cache in chrome, does it solve it?

Comment: This, together with your earlier question, describes, what, your third problem with Chrome, while at least one other browser works fine?  Why is the obvious fix not suitable for you?

Comment: @MartinJames Because it seem to be happening a lot and restarting my pc each time is a fix but there must be something i can do to make it stop.

Comment: @CNuts well, why can you not just use a browser that works reliably?  :)

Comment: @MartinJames You're right I don't mind using Edge, it would just be nice to know why this is happening. Chrome is supposed to be pretty reliable.

Comment: @MartinJames Also, it's a fair POV to not be sure if it's an SE vs. a local issue. I think it's worth reporting at least, just to see if anything comes of it.

Comment: @CNuts Part of me wonders if this might make a good question on https://superuser.com/, since we seem reasonably certain that it's entirely on your end. Although if you do that you'd want to be clear that you already asked it here, and lay out what you already found out from these posts.

Comment: @JasonC It could only help I guess. Should we migrate it?

Comment: @JasonC Don't know if this could be useful but it happens also sometimes on my brother laptop. Does this mean it's a network problem?

Comment: @CNuts The plot thickens. Maybe something funny that your router is doing?

Comment: @JasonC Maybe, I'm not really good with these things haha what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @CNuts I have no thoughts, myself, beyond just continuing to gather information. I'm great at telling computers what to do, but I have no idea how they work.

Comment: Routers are usually pretty cheap depending on where you are, I'd try a new router and see what happens. I've had routers go bad in the past and cause funny things to happen.

Comment: Does it work if you reboot your router?

Comment: @JasonC It started working again out of nowhere ill try it next time it does it

Comment: Look out your window. Are there UFOs? Do you have any conspicuous gaps in your memory?

Comment: @JasonC I did pass out for a couple of seconds on the couch and woke up with a funny feeling

Comment: @JasonC so yeah it stopped working again and it also stopped working on Edge too, I think they heard us

Comment: @JasonC Wait its back on Chrome but now its not working on Edge wtf is going on haha